# Want to fill in date range from 2 column values and link other columns for corresponding dates

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Fromdate always contains MONDAY
Todate always contain Sunday

The Sample data in view

| Fromdate | todate | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-09-23 | 24-09-23 | 203 | 405 | 505 | 605 | 415 | 355 | 205 |
| 15-08-22 | 21-08-22 | 266 | 305 | 345 | 715 | 205 | 505 | 165 |
| 22-08-22 | 28-08-22 | 203 | 405 | 505 | 605 | 405 | 345 | 605 |

We want to create a table with data in the format below

| Date | Budget |
| --- | --- |
| 18-09-23 | 203 |
| 19-09-23 | 405 |
| 20-09-23 | 505 |
| 21-09-23 | 605 |
| 22-09-23 | 415 |
| 23-09-23 | 355 |
| 24-09-23 | 205 |
| 15-08-22 | 266 |
| 16-08-22 | 305 |
| 17-08-22 | 345 |
| 18-08-22 | 715 |
| 19-08-22 | 205 |

and so on

Can any one provide a solution to the above problem? We are using Oracle SQL

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option to do it is to create a calendar CTE for period in your data, join it to your table and use Case expresssions to select data:

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, MON, TUE, WED, THU) AS
        ( Select DATE '2023-09-18', DATE '2023-09-21', 203, 405, 505, 605 
          From Dual 
        ), 
--  c a l e n d a r    C T E :
    cal AS
        ( Select  FROM_DATE + (LEVEL - 1) "DAY_ID", To_Char(FROM_DATE + (LEVEL - 1), 'DY') "DAY_SHORT" 
          From    tbl
          Connect By LEVEL <= (TO_DATE - FROM_DATE) + 1 
        )
```

```sql
--      M a i n    S Q L :
Select      c.DAY_ID "A_DATE", 
            Case  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'MON' Then t.MON
                  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'TUE' Then t.TUE
                  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'WED' Then t.WED
                  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'THU' Then t.THU
            End "BUDGET"
From        cal c
Inner Join  tbl t ON( c.DAY_ID Between t.FROM_DATE And t.TO_DATE )
```

```sql
/*    R e s u l t :
A_DATE        BUDGET
--------- ----------
18-SEP-23        203
19-SEP-23        405
20-SEP-23        505
21-SEP-23        605    */
```

NOTE: This is dependant on your NLS_ variables as it uses day name abreviations in case expressions. You, depending on your context, should adjust it to your needs or use day number of week (ISO) as your Case expression conditions. This answers the question with data provided and expected result. Otherwise it should be adjusted to your actual context.
EXample for two weeks data in your table:

```sql
WITH    -- 2 row sample data with all week days
    tbl (FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN) AS
        ( Select DATE '2023-09-18', DATE '2023-09-24', 203, 405, 505, 605, 0, 0, 0 From Dual Union All
          Select DATE '2023-09-25', DATE '2023-10-01', 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 0, 0 From Dual 
        ),
```

In case of 2 or more rows in your table create calendar for the period since Min(FROM_DATE) till Max(TO_DATE)

```sql
    cal AS
        ( Select  FROM_DATE + (LEVEL - 1) "DAY_ID", To_Char(FROM_DATE + (LEVEL - 1), 'DY') "DAY_SHORT" 
          From    (Select Min(FROM_DATE) "FROM_DATE", Max(TO_DATE) "TO_DATE" From tbl)
          Connect By LEVEL <= (TO_DATE - FROM_DATE) + 1 
        )
```

The same Main SQL should be adjusted for FRI, SAT, SUN in Case expression:

```sql
                  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'FRI' Then t.FRI
                  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'SAT' Then t.SAT
                  When c.DAY_SHORT = 'SUN' Then t.SUN
```

... resulting as

```sql
/*
A_DATE        BUDGET
--------- ----------
18-SEP-23        203
19-SEP-23        405
20-SEP-23        505
21-SEP-23        605
22-SEP-23          0
23-SEP-23          0
24-SEP-23          0
25-SEP-23        100
26-SEP-23        200
27-SEP-23        300
28-SEP-23        400
29-SEP-23        500
30-SEP-23          0
01-OCT-23          0  */
```

If there is a gap between rows (and/or incomplete week period) in your data like

```sql
WITH
    tbl (FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN) AS
        ( Select DATE '2023-09-18', DATE '2023-09-24', 203, 405, 505, 605, 0, 0, 0 From Dual Union All
          Select DATE '2024-02-01', DATE '2024-02-03', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 From Dual
        ),
```

... this will result as

```sql
/*
A_DATE        BUDGET
--------- ----------
18-SEP-23        203
19-SEP-23        405
20-SEP-23        505
21-SEP-23        605
22-SEP-23          0
23-SEP-23          0
24-SEP-23          0
01-FEB-24          4  -- THU
02-FEB-24          5  -- FRI
03-FEB-24          6  -- SAT      */
```

Answer (score 0):

That just doesn't seem OK to me. Is that "view", that contains sample data, really a *view* (database object, created with `CREATE VIEW` statement?) that contains only one row? Because, 18.09.2023 really was Monday. I wonder how it (the view) looks like if it contained two or more rows, e.g.

| Fromdate | todate | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-09-23 | 21-09-23 | 203 | 405 | 505 | 605 |
| 01-02-24 | 03-02-24 |  |  |  |  |

because 01.02.2024 was **not** Monday (it was Thursday) and column headings don't match any more.

Therefore, if that really is a one-row *view*, the simplest option to create a table based on that data is to

```
create table result (datum, budget) as
  select date '2023-09-18, 203 from dual union all
  select date '2023-09-19, 405 from dual union all
  select date '2023-09-20, 505 from dual union all
  select date '2023-09-21, 604 from dual;
```

If that's not the case, could you explain what "view" means and what data it really contains, in which columns?

---

**[EDIT]** After you fixed sample data:

```
SQL> select * From test order by fromdate;

FROMDATE   TODATE            MON        TUE        WED        THU        FRI        SAT        SUN
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
15.08.2022 21.08.2022        266        305        345        715        205        505        165
22.08.2022 28.08.2022        203        405        505        605        405        345        605
18.09.2023 24.09.2023        203        405        505        605        415        355        205
```

This is one option you might be interested in:

```
SQL> select fromdate + column_value - 1 as datum,
  2    case column_value when 1 then mon
  3                      when 2 then tue
  4                      when 3 then wed
  5                      when 4 then thu
  6                      when 5 then fri
  7                      when 6 then sat
  8                      when 7 then sun
  9    end budget
 10  from test cross join
 11    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                        connect by level <= todate - fromdate + 1
 13                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14  order by datum;

DATUM          BUDGET
---------- ----------
15.08.2022        266
16.08.2022        305
17.08.2022        345
18.08.2022        715
19.08.2022        205
20.08.2022        505
21.08.2022        165
22.08.2022        203
23.08.2022        405
24.08.2022        505
25.08.2022        605
26.08.2022        405
27.08.2022        345
28.08.2022        605
18.09.2023        203
19.09.2023        405
20.09.2023        505
21.09.2023        605
22.09.2023        415
23.09.2023        355
24.09.2023        205

21 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: from date starts with monday and to date ends with sunday .
and for corresponding dates we will have a day column in the view.
i have edited your comment with sample data

Comment: Don't edit **my** table; you should provide valid sample data in **your** question, so I rejected your edit attempt and suggest you edit the original question you posted.

Comment: sorry . i am new to this platform . will edit the question

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense. Thank you for effort you put into fixing it. Please, have a look at edited answer which shows one way to do it.